cachednetworkimage Reload images when moving to a page flutter
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q1sw0K0uLv4xuot09l7hvSWGnvc7szDG/view?usp=sharing
Every time I open a page and then come back, I find product images being reloaded
Random images are reloaded, not all images
When  I show a lot of products, then choose a product, then come back. A lot of random images will be loaded together, and this will affect the performance of the application.
I want to know the solution to the problem of reloading photos
This is how to navigate to the page
Get.toNamed(
                                          AppRoutes.productdetailspage,
                                          arguments: {
                                            "idproduct":
                                                controller.products[index]["id"]
                                          },
                                        );

This is the code for displaying images
Get.put(LatestProductsController());
    CachedNetworkImage(
                // cacheKey: cacheKey,
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                  AppImageAssets.logo,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
            ),

controller
getdata() async {
    statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading;
    var response = await productsData.getData();
    statusRequest = handlingData(response);
    if (StatusRequest.success == statusRequest) {
      if (response["status"] == true) {
        products.addAll(response["data"]);
        nextPageUrl = response["pagination"]["next_page_url"] ?? '';
      } 
    }
    update();
  } 
@override
  void onInit() async {
    getdata();
    super.onInit();
  }


are u calling the function/api call to get the products inside Init function or on load function?

i am sure its not just the images it also reload or fetches other attributes as well

I edited the post and added the controller
@user3509208

I think your problem is when u clicking on a product your initial screen is lost, which causes the init to be called again when u navigate back to the page

I am using Navigator.of(context) in my app without any issues i have the same flow as yours. I HAVE Navigator.of(context).push( CODE. LET ME KNOW IF YOU NEED MORE DETAILS

I don't think it will be called again because I put print and nothing appears @user3509208

not happening in my app, weird

I found a temporary solution
Increase the size of the temporary memory
 PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.maximumSizeBytes = 300 << 20;

Reduce the quality of images before storing them
 maxHeightDiskCache: 200,
                maxWidthDiskCache: 200,
                memCacheHeight: 200,
                memCacheWidth: 200,

